# "504 Gateway Timeout Error" while trying to access WordPress website hosted on AWS EC2 T2 micro instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have my WordPress website hosted on AWS EC2 T2 micro instance. Lately I am unable to access the website. The error is

> 504 Gateway Timeout".

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the web server software is not getting a timely response from whatever it is calling upstream.

The most likely set up that will give this error when trying access wordpress is nginx paired up with php-fpm.

Diagnosing the problem with so little information is next to impossible.  I would start with ensuring php-fpm is running.  If it is then check the error logs to find out why it is timing out.